# Using X Keycodes with no keyboard or multiple keyboards?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, raspberry-pi

In my laptop, I'm using QJoypad to map some buttons into key presses, so I can play some retro games with the arcade buttons. Qjoypad creates something like this:

```
Joystick 1 {
    Axis 1: +key 116, -key 111
    Axis 4: +key 113, -key 114
    Button 1: key 65
}
```

These numbers are X keycodes, which can be found with the `xev` program. From [here](https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-44F3733A-99C3-4F7E-BF2F-ECE932D4BA54.html):

> An X server uses a two-level encoding of keys, which includes the X key code and the keysym. An X key code is a one-byte value. The assignment of key codes to keys **depends on the X server implementation and the physical keyboard**. As a result, an X application normally cannot use key codes directly. Instead, the key codes are mapped into keysyms that have names like space, escape, x and 2.

However, I'm feeling confused here.

- What if I had 2 keyboards in my system?
- What if I have no keyboard (for example, with a Raspberry Pi)?

In this [tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Gamepad-Controlled-Raspberry-Pi-Using-Qjoypad/), the guy uses Qjoypad with the Raspberry Pi and an external keyboard. If the keyboard was removed, would things still work? **How would the X Keycodes be generated then?**

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard actions in X work by sending messages to applications that contain both the keycode (think: number for the position of the key on the keyboard) and the keysym (think: number for the actual symbol, e.g. <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>). The X infrastructure doesn't care where such an event comes from, you can synthesize it from another application `QJoypad`, or attach any number of keyboards to generate such events.

In fact, if you look at the device tree with `xinput`, you'll see multiple devices attached to the "virtual core keyboard", and all of those can generate key events (a number of those will be "power button" key events).

So: it doesn't matter if you have zero, two or hundred keyboards in your system, it just works.

However, you need both the keysym and the keycode. There are routines to find the matching keysum for a keycode (and vice versa), so I do hope `QJoypad` uses those.